# SwiftUI @Binding Initialize

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13

Been playing around with SwiftUI and understood the concept of `BindableObjects` etc so far (at least I hope I do).

I bumped into a stupid problem I can't seem to find an answer for: 
How do you initialize a `@Binding` variable?

I have the following code:

```swift
struct LoggedInView : View {

    @Binding var dismissView: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
}
```

In my preview code, I want to pass that parameter of type `Binding<Bool>`:

```swift
#if DEBUG
struct LoggedInView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoggedInView(dismissView: **Binding<Bool>**)
    }
}
#endif
```

How would I go an initialize it? tried:

```swift
Binding<Bool>.init(false)
Binding<Bool>(false)
```

Or even:

```swift
@Binding var dismissView: Bool = false
```

But none worked... any ideas?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

When you use your `LoggedInView` in your app you do need to provide some binding, such as an `@State` from a previous view or an `@EnvironmentObject`.

For the special case of the `PreviewProvider` where you just need a fixed value you can use `.constant(false)`

E.g.

```
#if DEBUG
struct LoggedInView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoggedInView(dismissView: .constant(false))
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: That looks elegant. I just wonder if it makes the property immutable for the live preview.

Comment: It is, but that is typically all you need for the preview

Comment: For a static preview, using immutable Binding.constant is fine, but it is totally unusable for a Live Preview where I wanna play around with just one view and see the value changed.

Comment: The solution of @NeverwinterMoon below is better, because it lets you interact with the canvas.

Answer (score 83):

Using `Binding.constant(false)` is fine but only for static previews. If you actually wanna launch a Live Preview, `constant` will not behave the same way as the real case as it will never be updated by your actions. I personally use Live Preview a lot, as I can play around with an isolated view.

Here is what I do for previews requiring `Binding`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
   @Binding var code: String

   var body: some View {
     // some views modifying code binding
   }
}

struct SomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    PreviewWrapper()
  }

  struct PreviewWrapper: View {
    @State(initialValue: "") var code: String

    var body: some View {
      SomeView(code: $code)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. But I'm wondering why adding a property like `@State static var code: String = ""` isn't enough?

Comment: It isn't enough as it doesn't work, unlike the proposed solution. With static var the property value just doesn't get updated and it works the same way as using Binding.constant - which is fine for a static preview only.

Comment: NeverwinterMoon I've used this in my code and it works like a charm (I needed a @State since I had a Binding<> call). Gave answer +1

Answer (score 12):

- If you need a simple property that belongs to a single view you
  should use **@State**
- If you need to have complex property that may
  belong to several view(like 2-3 views) you shall use
  **@ObjectBinding**
- Lastly, if you need to have property that needs to use all around views you shall use **@EnvironmentObject**.
  Source [for detail information](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-objectbinding-state-and-environmentobject)

For your case, if you still would like to initialize your Binding variable you can use:

```
var binding: Binding = .constant(false)
```

Comment: Note that since Xcode 11.3 Beta 5, (AT)ObjectBinding is now called (AT)ObservedObject (where (AT) = @)

Answer (score 2):

In preview you have to use `.constant(Bool(false))`:

```swift
#if DEBUG
struct LoggedInView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoggedInView(dismissView: .constant(Bool(false))
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

if you have an object like viewModel you can also use .constant()

```
struct View_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
     View(vm:.constant(ViewModel(text: "Sample Text")))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using different configurations of my view within one preview (I'm working on a custom control and want to see a different configuration of it). I've extended the implementation provided by @NeverwinterMoon in order to create multiple independent instances of a view.

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
   @Binding var value: Int

   var body: some View {
     // some views modifying code binding
   }
}

struct SomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    VStack {
      // The same view but with different configurations

      // Configuration #1
      PreviewWrapper() { value in
        SomeView(value: value)
          .background(Color.blue)
      }

      // Configuration #2      
      PreviewWrapper(initialValue: 2) { value in
        SomeView(value: value)
          .padding()
      }
    }
  }

  struct PreviewWrapper<Content: View>: View {
    @State var value: Int
    private let content: (Binding<Int>) -> Content
    
    init(
      initialValue: Int = 0,
      @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Binding<Int>) -> Content
    ) {
      self.value = initialValue
      self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
      content($value)
    }
  }
}
```