# How to print in SwiftUI Previews?

Tags: ios, logging, swiftui, swiftui-previews

I know [how to `print` in a SwiftUI view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517813/how-to-print-to-xcode-console-in-swiftui). I would like to do the same within a [**SwiftUI preview**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/previews-in-xcode) so that I don't need to run the app in the simulator to see the logs.

For example here I'm trying to print a view's frame size:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Image(systemName: "globe")
        .imageScale(.large)
        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
      Text("Hello, world!")
    }
    .padding()
    .background {
      GeometryReader { proxy in
        Color.clear
          .onAppear {
            print(proxy.size)
          }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

This outputs properly to the Xcode Console when running the app on the simulator. However, the Xcode Console doesn't show any output when the preview is shown. I tried both "Live" and "Selectable" mode in the SwiftUI preview to no avail.

---

I know I can switch the `print` to an `NSLog("SWIFTUIPREVIEWLOG: \(proxy.size)")` and then search for `SWIFTUIPREVIEWLOG` in Console.app, but this takes longer than reading the output from the Xcode Console. Plus, the output is messier when running in the simulator.

Is there a way to view `print` statements originating from SwiftUI previews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, attaching to Preview instances of your app has been deprecated. I have historically gone the Log route. Once you save a filter in Console, it can be … survivable. However, while trying to find an official source for the deprecation, I stumbled across this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690415) on the dev forums, and the last reply sounds hacky but interesting. As I haven’t yet had a chance to try this approach, I can’t speak to its reliability, but it seems worth a shot. (That said, you may also want to look into the [Inject](https://www.merowing.info/hot-reloading-in-swift/) framework, which makes live code injection for regular simulators fairly painless and often better than SwiftUI previews.)

Answer (score 3):

As of Xcode 14.3.1 There is Previews tabs in the output window that shows the previews.

If not available then there is a simple workaround for this;

1. Create a wrapper for the view;

```
struct ContentViewWrapper : View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Now, call this wrapper within the `PreviewProvider`

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentViewWrapper()
  }
}
}
```

Now, the prints are appearing on the console while playing with the preview.

Tested with Xcode 13.4!