# SwiftUI State in Preview with PreviewProvider is not working

Tags: swiftui, preview, swiftui-button, swiftui-state

I've a simple button that work on simulator as expected, the shape changes with click;

```swift
struct ButtonTest: View {
    @State var isLiked = true
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            LikeButtonSimple( action: toggleLiked, isLiked: $isLiked)
        }
    }
    func toggleLiked() {
    
        isLiked.toggle()
        print("Liked Button: \(isLiked)")
    }
}

struct LikeButtonSimple: View {
    
    let dimen = 50.0
    let dimenHalf = CGFloat(28)
    
    var action: () -> Void?
    
    @Binding var isLiked : Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: dimen, height: dimen)
                .foregroundColor(.white )
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2, y: 2)
            Button( action: {
               action()
            }
            ) {
                Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                    .resizable()
                    .foregroundColor(isLiked ? .red : .gray)
                    .frame(width: dimenHalf, height: dimenHalf)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to see the same behavior on the `Preview` as well and wrote the below for it;

```swift
struct LikeButtonSimple_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    @State static var isLiked = true

    static func toggleLiked() {

        isLiked.toggle()
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        LikeButtonSimple( action: toggleLiked, isLiked: $isLiked)

    }
}
```

The button doesn't toggle anymore. Can we work this on Preview with this PreviewProvider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Xcode `Preview` is **static**, it can't hold changed value of variable.

To change value in `Preview`, you will have to use the container view inside it which will holds the state value.

```
struct LikeButtonSimple_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    //A view which will wraps the actual view and holds state variable. 
    struct ContainerView: View {
        @State private var isLiked = true
        
        var body: some View {
            LikeButtonSimple(action: toggleLiked, isLiked: $isLiked)
        }
        
        func toggleLiked() {
            isLiked.toggle()
        }
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        ContainerView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It seems the [one of the ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66175501/1820553). Even more, a constant can be provided so that isLiked doesn't need to have initial value.

Comment: You can't get the updated value when you will use `.constant(true)` instead of `State` var.

Comment: `ContainerView(isLiked = true)`is working, I've tested and removed the initialization of isLiked

Comment: Yes, that way also you can initialise the isLiked value.

Comment: @kelalaka this is exactly what I meant in the last comment on my answer.  I’m on my phone and couldn’t update though. This is not coding style. This is how to easily make a preview.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don’t need the action here at all.

A binding is a two way connection to some data.

By using a binding the view that you pass it to can make updates to it.

So you do not need the bonding and the action. The button action should just do…

```swift
isLiked.toggle()
```

This is enough for the view to update and for the value to be updated in the “parent” view.

Comment: Well, it was part of some design consideration. Even, I can remove the action and call toggle inside of the button's action, the PreviewProvider doesn't behave correctly. So there is something else about this...

Comment: Can you not use the container view. The ButtonTest view in the preview provider. That way it already has the binding baked into it

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it. Could you elaborate it? This is running normally in the app, I just want to create a preview.

Comment: But the preview could just be a view that contains the button rather than making the preview just the button itself.

Comment: I think you are talking how to code in some style, all I want to ability of preview the design updates on preview even after integration of the view..

Comment: Yes, you are right about that I don't need to toggle with a function, I was testing capabilites...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when we use SwiftUI `#Preview` macros.

```swift
#Preview {
    @State var isVisible: Bool = false
    return ChatView(isVisibleView: $isVisible)
}
```