# Passing to a SwiftUI struct, a binding value

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hopefully, this is an easy question.  I am attempting to pass to the FilterViewa struct from the FilterView_Previews struct @Binding value that is a Bool like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FilterView: View {
     @Binding var isNavigationBarHidden: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Filters go here")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .onAppear {
            self.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct FilterView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    var isHidden: Bool = true
    
    static var previews: some View {
        FilterView(isNavigationBarHidden: isHidden)
    }
}
#endif
```

However, the value **isHidden** is getting flagged with a 'Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding'.  In this scenario, how do you create an appropriate @Binding value within the FilterView_Previews struct that satisfies the compiler?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI @Binding Initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685964/swiftui-binding-initialize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a *constant* Binding when in previews:

```
struct FilterView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FilterView(isNavigationBarHidden: .constant(true))
    }
}
```

Comment: That does work and thank you for that.  How would you create a variable that would be a Binding<Bool> value rather than just passing in a constant?

Comment: @PerryHoekstra Actually I've just realised this question has already been asked before. Please refer to the post I suggested for more explanation.